# Using C#, how can I get a jobId for Bulk Api 2.0?

Tags: rest, bulk-api, c#, azure, jobid

I am trying to set data from an Azure Service Bus to an instance of Salesforce using the Bulk API 2.0 and and REST (because who really wants to deal with SOAP?).

I am currently struggling "simply" to get a `jobId` which I can hang the rest of this process on.

This is my method so-far:

```
        private string CreateJob(String sObjectType, AuthenticationToken token, IConfigurationRoot config) {
            this.log.LogInformation($"####### TOKEN: {token.Access_token}");
            this.log.LogInformation($"####### URL: {config["SalesforceBulkApi2Endpoint"]}jobs/ingest");
            this.log.LogInformation($"####### BODY: {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new JobRequestBody("Account"))}");

            IRestRequest request = new RestRequest($"{config["SalesforceBulkApi2Endpoint"]}jobs/ingest")
                .AddHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer {token.Access_token}")
                .AddHeader("Accept", "application/json")
                .AddParameter("application/json", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new JobRequestBody(sObjectType)), ParameterType.RequestBody);

            IRestResponse response = new RestClient(config["SalesforceInstanceBaseUrl"])
                .Post(request);

            this.log.LogInformation("####### response" + response);
            this.log.LogInformation("####### response.Content " + response.Content);

            if (!response.IsSuccessful) {
                throw new SaleforceServiceException("Cannot create job", response);
            }

            return null;
        }
```

In my local.settings.json (cause I am still working locally), I have the following relevant values:

```
    "SalesforceLoginEndpoint": "https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token",
    "SalesforceInstanceBaseUrl": "https://enpal--bmk84.lightning.force.com/",
    "SalesforceBulkApi2Endpoint": "/services/data/v48.0/",
```

...as well as values for creating the token which seems to be working.

However the above code always fails throwing an exception, from which I see:
"[{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]"

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Decided to use HttpClient instead of RestClient (perhaps not so important) and then made various other changes.  This was the final, working result:

C#:

```
        private string CreateJob(String sObjectType, AuthenticationToken token, IConfigurationRoot config) {
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            string jsonResponse;
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient()) {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.Access_token);

                string url = $"{config["SalesforceInstanceBaseUrl"]}/services/data/{config["SalesforceVersion"]}/jobs/ingest";
                string jobRequest = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new JobRequestBody(sObjectType));
                StringContent content = new StringContent(jobRequest, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                jsonResponse = client.PostAsync(url,content)
                    .Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
                    .Result;
            }

            dynamic jobResponse = JObject.Parse(jsonResponse);
            return jobResponse.id;
        }
```

Settings:

```
    "SalesforceInstanceBaseUrl": "https://enpal--bmk84.my.salesforce.com/",
    "SalesforceVersion": "v48.0",
```